# Are death risks by cesarean deliveries higher in teenagers?

Tags: childbirth

According to this article [Complications of cesarean deliveries](https://www.medscape.org/viewarticle/512946_4) risks of death by cesarean delivery are between 0.53 to 0.13 per 1,000 cesarean deliveries. I've seen and heard many times this claim that childbirth in teenagers has a higher risk of death, in internet and TV, but never studies or statistics are mentioned.

For example, in the [WHO webpage on Adolescent Pregnancy](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/adolescent-pregnancy) it says,

> Pregnancy and childbirth complications are the leading cause of death among 15 to 19 year-old girls globally,"

There is also,

> Adolescent pregnancy (i.e., in females 13 to 19 years of age) is associated with an increased risk of maternal complications during pregnancy and delivery (Source: [AAFP](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2007/0501/p1310.html))

Personally, I dont see why a cesarean delivery should be more complicated in teenagers than in adults, but I've seen and heard the claim than is more complicated in the delivery dozens of times, with no proof or evidence or study which sustains it. That's why I'm asking

Are there any researchs or stats which shows these risks by cesarean delivery are higher in teenagers if this is really so?

Comment: I don't think deaths due to pregnancy and childbirth complications are going to correlate well with deaths during cesarean deliveries. I would expect teenagers, in fact, to have a lower death rate since youth confers a lot of physical resilience. Also, the very fact that they're having a cesarean delivery suggests they have access to modern medical care. I'm sure many of the deaths reported in the WHO report are due to lack thereof.

Comment: The statement "Pregnancy and childbirth complications are the leading cause of death among 15 to 19 year-old girls globally" describes pregnancy as a leading cause of death *among 15 to 19 year old girls* who presumably have few other common causes of death. It says nothing about whether pregnancy and childbirth complications are more common in 15 to 19 year olds versus other age ranges.

Comment: Here you have another one "Adolescent pregnancy (i.e., in females 13 to 19 years of age) is associated with an increased risk of maternal complications during pregnancy and delivery," https://www.aafp.org/afp/2007/0501/p1310.html . Personally, I dont see why a cesarean delivery should be more complicated in teenagers than in adults, but I've seen and heard the claim than is more complicated in the delivery dozens of times, with no proof or evidence or study which sustains it. That's why I'm asking

Comment: Again, I don't think complications during pregnancy and delivery are going to correlate with cesarean deaths. Apples and oranges.

Comment: "Delivery" in some contexts includes cesarean delivery, and in other (perhaps most) contexts only includes vaginal delivery.  Whenever an article does not specify, there is no way to know.  The wording for the AAFP source "...complications during pregnancy and delivery" suggests that it does not include cesarean.  You would need to look at statistics specific to cesarean delivery to answer your question.